# Ignore click on TListView checkbox

Tags: delphi, checkbox, delphi-xe5, tlistview

I have a `TListview` where I want to use the checkboxes to indicate whether an event has happened to an item in the list.

I can read and set the checkbox status, but what I really want to do is disable the ability of the user to change the status using a mouse click.

For a `TCheckList` I can set the `checked` state to the inverse using OnClickCheck

The same doesn't work for a `TListview`.  At them moment I can see that the checkbox has been targeted in `OnMouseDown` but can't disable the click from going through..

```
procedure TMF.ListViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
   MyHitTest : THitTests;
begin
   MyHitTest := (Sender as TListView).GetHitTestInfoAt(X,Y);
   if htOnStateIcon in MyHitTest then
      (Sender as TListView).OnMouseDown := nil;
end;
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Does setting the Enabled property of the TListView to false help?

Comment: Nope.  I need the Items to available to be clicked individually (am using `Rowselect`), just the state of the checkboxes needs to be in my control

Comment: You are fighting the system here. It doesn't want to let you do this. In your position I'd be looking for a solution not involving the built in check boxes.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I have no problem with adding and removing checkboxes with code while the user cannot (un)check the DISABLED TListView. What is your listview's `ViewStyle`? Also, there are the `OnChange` and `OnChanging` events that look like exactly what you want.

Comment: @Gunther I'm using vsReport - I'm assuming both you and David are suggesting I roll-my-own checkboxes rather than using the default ones.  Both of which answers my question that there's no way to do it as shipped.

Comment: I would not roll your own checkboxes. I'd just add another column and report the status in text form in that column. You could perhaps use a Unicode character for a tick: ✓

Comment: I still fail to see a problem. You have a `TListView` with `CheckBoxes=True` and `ViewStyle=vsReport`. You want to be able to tick checkboxes by code, but the listview should stay readonly to the user. Right? You can use either the `OnChanging` or `OnChange` event for that to revert the `TListItems`'s `Checked` state to what you want it to be. This way you can even make only certain checkboxes appear readonly.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful I've done a little test and the problem with `OnChange` is that it is being called even if you don't change the item (Delphi XE). Example when the user use arrows keys from the keyboard to move from one item to another. Not sure this is a bug tougth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the event `Onchanging` and set `AllowChange` to `False`.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Change: TItemChange; var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  AllowChange := False;
end;
```

Update: OP want the user to be able to select the item. So, maybe, a little hack using `OnItemChecked` event can do.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemChecked(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  if TComponent(Sender).Tag = 0 then
  begin
    TComponent(Sender).Tag := 1;
    Item.Checked := not Item.Checked;
    TComponent(Sender).Tag := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Update2: The problem using this trick is that you must disable it before you change any item status. For example:

```
Procedure LoadListViewItems;
begin
  //Let's permit modification in ListView Items.
  ListView1.OnItemChecked := nil;
  try
    //put Load Items code Here!
  finally
    //User cannot change Items statuses 
    ListView1.OnItemChecked := ListView1ItemChecked;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should check the `Change` parameter before blindly disallowing all changes: `if Change = ctState then AllowChange := False;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau besides this was only one example, I don't understand why. If he don't want to allow the changes in anytime, what's the difference?

Comment: This was quite a head scratcher for me. OP may have wanted this as a permanent rule, while I wanted this in a read-only mode of my app - where user checks on which items they want to do "something" with, and then press a button which iterates through all items and does that "something", during which time the user isn't allowed to toggle these checkboxes. So I ended up with way extra code than you.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes! This is, like David said in comment, "figthing the system". So more code are needed to do simple things. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could hook the window proc to force the item checked state before any VCL event handling takes place:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    fLVWndProc: TWndProc;
  end;


  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    // Save the original window proc and install the hook

    fLVWndProc := Listview1.WindowProc;
    Listview1.WindowProc := LVWndProcHook;
  end;



  procedure TForm1.LVWndProcHook(var aMessage: TMessage) ;
  var
    notify: PNMListView;
    bItemState: Boolean;
  begin
    if (aMessage.Msg = CN_NOTIFY)
     and (PNMHdr(aMessage.LParam).Code = LVN_ITEMCHANGED) then
    begin
      notify := PNMListView(aMessage.LParam);

      if ((notify.uChanged and LVIF_STATE) <> 0) then
      begin
        // Determine actual item state and re-apply it before continuing
        bItemState := GetUnderlyingItemState(notify.iItem);
        ListView_SetCheckState(notify.hdr.hwndFrom, notify.iItem, bItemState);
      end;
    end;

    //original ListView message handling
    fLVWndProc(aMessage) ;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListItemChecked(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 if not CheckBoxesEnabled then begin
  List.OnItemChecked:=nil;
  Item.Checked:=not Item.Checked;
  List.OnItemChecked:=ListItemChecked;
 end;
end;
```

*List* is your TListView, and *CheckBoxesEnabled* a boolean variable that enable or disable the checkboxes.